# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery Error in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, iis, windows-server-2016

I have the following problem. ASP website that is using and web api hosted on the windows server 2012. The site is working true VS but when i deploy it to production i got the following error:

```
20-04-24 08:55:56.365 +03:00 [Error] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery] [{ Id: 7, Name: "TokenDeserializeException" }] An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
 ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {e790d979-a748-4094-8c5e-d3496ca4f915} was not found in the key ring.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.GetCookieTokenDoesNotThrow(HttpContext httpContext)
```

I am using the same database and connection string same endpoint

Comment: Have you changed any of the DataProtection settings? What dotnet core version are you using? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: 3.1 i will check the settings right away. but i haven't change a thing

Comment: It's just new Server. I added IIS to it and dotnet-sdk-3.1.201-win-x64

Answer (score 1):

Had OP mentioned error message combined with these:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {327bb8b3-8add-4eb2-9bc9-edf358f19a3a} was not found in the key ring.

ApplicationUserAccessor _context.HttpContext null.

warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[59]

warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository[50]
```

Defining AddDataProtection to UNC folder as per docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-3.1#persistkeystofilesystem) solved all these messages.

Here's sample of my code:

```
    var pgrmData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
    Directory.CreateDirectory($"{pgrmData}\\myaspnetwebapp\\keys");
    services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo($"{pgrmData}\\myaspnetwebapp\\keys"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the OP didn't provide enough details, I want to provide a solution that worked for me. In my case, I have an ASP.NET Core MVC view that posts to a controller action. Adding the `asp-antiforgery` attribute fixed the issue for me.

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" method="post" asp-antiforgery="false">
   ...
</form>
```

Per verbatim from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-5.0#aspnet-core-antiforgery-configuration):

- In ASP.NET Core 2.0 or later, the FormTagHelper injects antiforgery tokens into HTML form elements.
- Similarly, IHtmlHelper.BeginForm generates antiforgery tokens by default if the form's method isn't GET.

Comment: This opens up your forms to forgery hacking attacks... this does not solve the issue, only covers up the symptoms and worse, creates a dangerous vulnerability in your app...